# Energy contribution due to matter transfer

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I have a very important question that lingers in my mind for a long time:

In the fundamental relations of Gibbsian Thermodynamics,

[image: equation]

I simply don't understand how the last term appears. 
I have checked some reference books and it is said the last term can be interpreted as the energy contribution due to matter transfer at constant volume and entropy. 
But why does matter transfer contribute to the energy of the system? Can anyone illustrate this with an example? Much thanks!!!

Comment: In phase transitions away from the equilibrium point, you will have changes in the number of particles (atoms, molecules) from one phase to another, and since each of those phases has a different chemical potential you have a change in the Gibbs free energy of the system. Consider a steam engine, where the driving force is the condensation of steam in to water.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. But the definition of chemical potential as far as I know is derived exactly from the last term. So I still can't understand why there is a change in the Gibbs free energy. Could you explain it on a microscopic level what kinds of energy is lost in matter transfer?

Comment: Well, the steam engine part was the example. Take a container with half steam and half water in equilibrium. Slide a plate across the head space, cutting off half the steam from the system. Lots of free energy just went away.